# How can I create a word using a font with my own pictures in it?

Tags: images, photo-editing, font-design

I'm not very technical and want to know if there is an app or software I can download to put my own photos into a letter to create my own font? Like the word MUMMY done but eith images of her children filling the letter?

Comment: You don't mention what software you have access too but generally this will be done with Clipping Mask. We've got numerous questions on the subject. As I don't know what software you'll be using I can't mark a specific duplicate but have a look at these http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=clipping+mask --- you can also use Google/Bing to search for clipping mask tutorials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illustrator clipping masks containing images and text](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7957/illustrator-clipping-masks-containing-images-and-text)

Comment: Are you looking to create something [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m2rxY.png), or an image effect [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xUOFu.png)?

Comment: @JohnB I'm going to guess they would like the second

Comment: I think you're asking for something like clipping masks, like [How to turn text into a “hole” in a layer, so I will see the background through it](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7447/adobe-photoshop-how-to-turn-text-into-a-hole-in-a-layer-so-i-will-see-the-b), but using something simpler than Photoshop? I imagine there's probably some free online service but it's not something designers are likely to know about (maybe try asking at http://webapps.stackexchange.com ?). This is also sometimes called **knockout text**

Comment: There's no practical way to create a font with photos in it. The way font files are built, they aren't made for multi-color photographs (there are rare exceptions but not the norm). If you just want to make a picture featuring photos inside of letters, then the answers above will steer you in the right direction

Comment: Obligatory joke answer: Physically arrange actual children in shape of the desired word and photograph them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you will use Adobe Photoshop to make this work. So here are the steps for it:

- Open a new template.
- Write the word Mummy on the new layer.
- Now drag and drop the image you want to bring over the text in this template. After bringing the image, right click on the layer of the image and click on "Create Clipping Mask".
- The image will now be in the text, you can resize the image according to your want.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hi UserSum, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thank you. I hope to help the users with answer whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using adobe illustrator if you intend on creating a font, write a letter, right click on it, select Create Outlines, place an image over it, select them both and press Ctrl+7 (Clipping Mask). (You can do the same with the entire word, not just one letter.)

It would be best if your images were vectorial cause of not, you will experience "bad things" when using the font and choosing a big font size.